# Counting M2M objects in Django

Tags: django, model, count, many-to-many

I have the following model:

> class Task(Model):
>
> ```
> solvers = ManyToManyField(User, related_name='slvrs')
> ```

Now I want to count the total number of solvers of all the tasks.
For example there are 3 Task objects in the database. The first one has been solved by 2 users (M2M field relates to 2 users), the second by 3 and the last one by 0.
I should get the count of all these solvers: 2 + 3 + 0 = 5.

I believe I have to use Count aggregate, but I have know idea on which models and which annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Task.objects.aggregate(count=Count('solvers'))['count']
```

Should get you what you need.